# Srcset attribute - max-width issue

Tags: html, css, srcset

I have following markup in html
`

```
<picture>
   <source 
         srcset="img/home-page/placeholders/placeholder_2560.jpg" 
         media="(max-width: 2560px)">
   <source 
         srcset="img/home-page/placeholders/placeholder_1920.jpg" 
         media="(max-width: 1920px)">
   <source 
         srcset="img/home-page/placeholders/placeholder_1600.jpg" 
         media="(max-width: 1600px)">
   <source 
         srcset="img/home-page/placeholders/placeholder_1336.jpg" 
         media="(max-width: 1366px)">
   <source 
         srcset="img/home-page/placeholders/placeholder_1200.jpg" 
         media="(max-width: 1200px)">
   <source 
         srcset="img/home-page/placeholders/placeholder_991.jpg" 
         media="(max-width: 991px)">
   <source 
         srcset="img/home-page/placeholders/placeholder_767.jpg" 
         media="(max-width: 767px)">
   <source 
         srcset="img/home-page/placeholders/placeholder_480.jpg" 
         media="(max-width: 480px)">
   <source 
         srcset="img/home-page/placeholders/placeholder_360.jpg" 
         media="(max-width: 360px)">
   <img 
         srcset="img/home-page/placeholders/placeholder_2560.jpg" alt="">
</picture>
```

`

Images are not showing if media is set to max-width, but working when set to min-width.

Any advice?

Comment: reverse the sources order.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude thanks, that works. How to apply min-device-pixel-ratio inside media? I mean i have 2 sets of images for retina and for normal screens. Still i have added below another set of sources with media condition.

Comment: You can add mediaqueries inside media attribute . I will add an answer

Comment: The browsers use the first condition they finds true, unlike regular css would do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you reverse the sources order it will work because it applies in the correct order. So your final code:

```
<picture>
   <source 
         srcset="img/home-page/placeholders/placeholder_360.jpg" 
         media="(max-width: 360px)">
   <source 
         srcset="img/home-page/placeholders/placeholder_480.jpg" 
         media="(max-width: 480px)">
   <source 
         srcset="img/home-page/placeholders/placeholder_767.jpg" 
         media="(max-width: 767px)">
   <source 
         srcset="img/home-page/placeholders/placeholder_991.jpg" 
         media="(max-width: 991px)">
   <source 
         srcset="img/home-page/placeholders/placeholder_1200.jpg" 
         media="(max-width: 1200px)">
   <source 
         srcset="img/home-page/placeholders/placeholder_1336.jpg" 
         media="(max-width: 1366px)">
   <source 
         srcset="img/home-page/placeholders/placeholder_1600.jpg" 
         media="(max-width: 1600px)">
   <source 
         srcset="img/home-page/placeholders/placeholder_1920.jpg" 
         media="(max-width: 1920px)">
   <source 
         srcset="img/home-page/placeholders/placeholder_2560.jpg" 
         media="(max-width: 2560px)">
   <img 
         srcset="img/home-page/placeholders/placeholder_2560.jpg" alt="">
</picture>
```

If you want to apply another media, like min-device-pixel-ratio as your comment request, you can add it no problem:

```
   <source 
         srcset="img/home-page/placeholders/placeholder_2560-3.jpg" 
         media="(max-width: 2560px) and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)">
```

or

```
   <source 
         srcset="img/home-page/placeholders/placeholder_2560-3.jpg" 
         media="(min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)">
```

Comment: Reverse order is working! Combining 2 rules with px ratio 1 and px ratio 2 is little problematic. What order is for that?